# Formal steps for gradient boosting with softmax and cross entropy loss function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, boosting, softmax, differential-equations

Consider some data  $\{(x_i,y_i)\}^n_{i=1}$ and a differentiable loss function $\mathcal{L}(y,F(x))$ and a multiclass classification problem which should be solved by a gradient boosting algorithm.

**EDIT:**

Björn mentioned in the comments that the softmax function is not a loss function. The more appropriate term is **softmax loss** (function) or **cross-entropy loss** (function).
Thanks for pointing out.

**END EDIT**

Let therefore be the cross-entropy loss function defined by the class probabilities gained from the softmax function so that :
\begin{equation}
softmax =F(x) = \hat{y}_i = \dfrac{e^{y_i}}{\sum_{k=1}^N e^{y_k}} \\
\mathcal{L}(y_i,\hat{y}_i) = -\sum_{} y_i \log \hat{y}_i
\label{eq:softmax:loss}
\end{equation}

where $y_i$ defines the the relative frequencies of each class in our target variable $y$.

In this case we end up with the partial derivatives for the softmax function
\begin{equation}
D_j\operatorname{softmax}_i = \dfrac{\delta softmax_i}{\delta y_j} = \left[\begin{array}{rll}
D_{1} \operatorname{softmax}_{1} & \times & D_{N} \operatorname{softmax}_{1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
D_{1} \operatorname{softmax}_{N} & \times & D_{N} \operatorname{softmax}_{N}
\end{array}\right]
\label{eq:dsoftmax}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D_{j} \text { softmax }_{i}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\operatorname{softmax}_{i}-\operatorname{softmax}_{j}^2 & i=j \\
-\operatorname{softmax}_{j} \times \operatorname{softmax}_{i} & i \neq j
\end{array}\right\}
\end{equation}

And the derrivative of the cross-entropy loss function w.r.t $\ \hat{y}_i$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \hat{y}_{i}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial F(x)}\left(-\sum_{i} y_{i} \log \hat{y}_{i}\right)=-\frac{y_{i}}{\hat{y}_{i}}
\end{equation}

Combining both gradients leads to the gradient of the loss function
(https://jmlb.github.io/ml/2017/12/26/Calculate_Gradient_Softmax/)
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial F(x)} &=-\frac{y_{i}}{\hat{y}_{i}} \hat{y}_{i}\left(1-\hat{y}_{i}\right)+\underbrace{\sum_{t \neq i}-\frac{y_{t}}{\hat{y}_{t}}}\left(-\hat{y}_{t} \hat{y}_{i}\right)\\
&=-y_{i}+y_{i} \hat{y}_{i}+\sum_{t \neq i} y_{t} \hat{y}_{i} \\
&=-y_{i}+\sum_{t} y_{t} \hat{y}_{i}\\
& =\hat{y}_{i} \underbrace{\sum_{t} y_{t}}_{=1}-y_{i}\\
& = \hat{y}_i - y_i
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In this sense our initial prediction should be :
\begin{equation}
 F_{0}(x)= \dfrac{e^{y_i}}{\sum_{k=1}^N e^{y_k}}  \\
 \end{equation}

One obtains the intial residuals $r_{i0}=y_i - F_0(x)$ which are then used to fit a classification tree with $R_{im}$ terminal nodes.

The pseudo residuals are obtained through
\begin{equation}
r_{im} = -\left[\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}\left(y_{i}, F\left(x_{i}\right)\right)}{\partial F\left(x_{i}\right)}\right]_{F(x)=F_{m-1}(x)} \text { for } i=1, \ldots, n \\
= -\sum_{i = 1}^N(\hat{y}_i - y_i) \\
= \sum_{i = 1}^N (y_i -\hat{y}_i) 
\end{equation}

and so the output values for each terminal node should be given by
\begin{equation}
\gamma_{lm} = \underset{\gamma}{\operatorname{argmin}} \sum_{x_{i} \in R_{lm}} L\left(y_{i}, F_{m-1}\left(x_{i}\right)+\gamma\right) \\
 \approx - \left[\mathcal{L}\left(y_{i}, F\left(x_{i}\right)\right) +  \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}\left(y_{i}, F\left(x_{i}\right)\right)}{\partial F\left(x_{i}\right)} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}\left(y_{i}, F\left(x_{i}\right)\right)}{\partial^2 F\left(x_{i}\right)}\right] \\
=  y_ilog(\hat{y}_i) + \sum_{i = 1}^N (y_i -\hat{y}_i)   - 1
\end{equation}

In the end our new predictions should be :
\begin{equation}
F_{m}(x)=F_{m-1}(x)+\nu \sum_{j=1}^{m} \gamma_{j m} I\left(x \in R_{j m}\right)
\end{equation}

**Question 1 : Given that the combined gradient of the softmax function and the cross-entropy loss function is correct in this model. Why is $y_i\hat{y}_i = 0$ in step 2 of gradient the simplification?**

**EDIT:**
**Why is $y_i\hat{y}_i = 0$ in step 2 of gradient the simplification?**

$y_i\hat{y}_i \neq 0$ the author just abused that $y_i\hat{y}_i + \sum_{t\neq i} y_t\hat{y}_i=\sum_{t} y_t\hat{y}_i$ because we can add $y_i\hat{y}_i$ to the sum by adjusting the index of the sum to be just $t$. Thereby promising that $t=i$ is possible.

**END EDIT**
**Question 2 : Are these steps formally correct? Is there anything to improve comprehensibility?**

Comment: Do you really mean using the softmax function as the loss function? Or do you mean that you have a multi-class prediction problem and want to predict probabilities by class, possibly using the softmax activation function, if necessary? If so, is your loss function perhaps the categorical cross-entropy (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy)?

Comment: >Do you really mean using the softmax function as the loss function?

To the best of my knowledge, yes. For gradient boosting models you have a loss function to evaluate the optimal tree output value. 

See the Algorithm section here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting

Comment: The softmax function is not a loss function (at least I cannot think of a way one would meaningfully use it as one), it turns a set of numbers in $(-\infty, \infty)$ into a simplex (i.e. a set of numbers in (0,1) that add up to 1).

Comment: Ok I think I found some slides which might shift the solution more into your direction!https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~milos/courses/cs2750-Spring2015/Lectures/Class12.pdf 
Have a look at slide 13 (softmax algo) and 15 (log-likelihood-trick). It seems your cross-entropy call was right?

Comment: Ok I almost surely convinced that you were right from the beginning. The answer on Quora (https://www.quora.com/Is-the-softmax-loss-the-same-as-the-cross-entropy-loss) backs your argument aswell! Thanks for clarifying the terms. I guess the things I mixed up were "**softmax loss**  which led me to the softmax function but **softmax loss** is really nothing else than the **cross-entropy-loss**!

I will edit my question with your input and see if question 1 will be solved afterwards!

Comment: I adjusted the question w.r.t. your insights! Maybe you can check the formal derivations of the steps aswell!

Comment: If I understand what you have here, you have already answered question 1 yourself, right? That quantity doesn't equal zero, it was just brought into the sum

Comment: That is correct.